# Problem with items.push - need string but getting object Object

Tags: jquery

This is part of my code. Maybe it is a little implicity but problem is easy to localize, i think. I want variable `notions` to be something which when i add this i will add words of notions, not `object Object` like i have now.
With this code i see that it makes good `$link` as my links but i can't combine it to one `<span>` element or something which could i use as `notions` variable when i am pushin items by `items.push`:

```
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        var notions = [];                           
        var tags = data[0].extras.tags.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '').split(', ');
        var id = data[0].pk
        $.each(tags, function(i,v){
             var tag = v.match(/<Tag:\s(.*)>/);
             if(tag !== null){
                 var href = '/notion/';
                 var $link = $('<a/>').attr('href', href+tag[1]).text(tag[1]);                                                           
                 notions = notions + $link + '&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
                 console.log($link); 
             }
         });        

         items.push('<li style="border: 1px solid black; list-style-type: none" ' + 'id="' +         value.pk + '"' + 'name="' + value.fields.depth + '">' +
          '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="zero">()</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +                                
          '<a href="' + value.extras.get_absolute_url_for_user + '">' + 
          '<span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS,Liberation San; font-size: 125%">' +  value.fields.title + '</span></a> <br />' +                                
          '<a href="' + value.extras.get_my_url + '">' +
          '<p style="vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0">' +
          '<img style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle" src="' + MEDIA_URL + 
          'own/i2.png" title="Show this in 1"></a>' +
          '<img class="delete_item" name="' + value.pk + '"' + 
          '" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle" src="' + MEDIA_URL + 
          'own/minus.png" title="Delete this">' +                                
          '<img class="get_item_form" name="' + value.pk + 
          '" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle" src="' + MEDIA_URL + 
          'own/plus.png" title="Add item">' + 
          notions +                               
         '</p></li>'); 
         $( '<ul/>', { html: items.join('') } ).insertAfter( nevermind );

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an object with `$('<a/>')` then adding it to `notions`. If you want the string, try getting the html of the object you created. That mess in `items.push` is illegible.

Comment: Don't know how. But if you want a string, you could also... just use a string, instead of creating an element.

Comment: This is no mess, but it only looks like it.

Comment: If it looks like a mess, debugs like a mess... it's probably a mess ;) All the CSS should be in CSS (particularly since it's repeated), and that much string concatenation in one place is atrocious to debug :)

Comment: Should or not should. Principle number one: first of all: it should work. If i found something working only then i could try find beter solutions. This is XXI century :)

Comment: Meh; stuff like not-online-CSS, at least, is pretty much a foregone conclusion--'cuz it's the 21st century, and we know better now :)

Comment: Faster vs Better? Faster is faster then Better and too fast fo it:D

Comment: It is normal. Thank You for help :)